# "PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions" when firestore function called using google cloud task

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I have created one function which adds an entry to the Firestore database.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const original = 'dhara';
    const writeResult = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
    res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
});
```

Created queue by following command

```
gcloud tasks queues create auction-autobid-queue
```

Then created Google Cloud Task.

```
const serviceAccount = require('./my-service-account.json');

const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');

const client = new CloudTasksClient({
  credentials: serviceAccount
});

async function createTask() {
     const project = 'my-project';
     const queue = 'auction-autobid-queue';
     const location = 'europe-west1';
     const payload = 'Hello, World!';
     const serviceAccountEmail = "my-name@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
      const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);
  
    const task = {
      httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: 'GET',
        url: 'https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/addMessage',
        oidcToken: {
          serviceAccountEmail,
        },
      },
    };
  
    const inSeconds = 60;
    if (inSeconds) {
     task.scheduleTime = {
        seconds: inSeconds + Date.now() / 1000
      };
    }
  
    console.log('Sending task:');
    console.log(task);
    const request = {parent, task};
    const [response] = await client.createTask(request);
    const name = response.name;
    console.log(`Created task ${name}`);
  }

  process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });

  createTask();
```

I added this task to an queue. Now when I run this task from the Google Cloud Console, it throws error.  I checked in firebase functions log and I can see function called but it throws me

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

[image]

I have a service account which has
**Cloud Functions Developer**
**Cloud Functions Service Agent**
**Owner** Roles.

I can't get what is the issue here as assigned roles are pretty good.

Comment: Did you assign an IAM Cloud Tasks role to the service account? https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-tasks-roles

Comment: Hello @JohnHanley I have assigned the "Cloud Functions Developer
, Cloud Functions Service Agent,
Cloud Tasks Admin,
Cloud Tasks Task Runner,
Owner" roles but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I found the answer after lots of struggle,

There was a default service account "App Engine default service account" is assigned to the function. It is not using my service account

So I checked if IAM has that service account is added as a member or not for the project. For my case, there was not added so I added the default service account to the project then assigned the **Owner** role. But by assigning only the owner role it was not working so I added two other roles **Cloud Functions Admin**, **Cloud Tasks Admin**. After this, my function saved data to the database.

Hope this will help to others.

Answer (score 2):

Your firestore database may not linked properly because you didn't initialize it with the serviceAccountKey.

Find your serviceAccountKey on: Firebase dashboard -> Project Settings -> Service Accounts tab

Download that json file, rename it and copy it to your source folder, in my case I renamed it as "myServiceKey.json"

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./myServiceKey.json");

const firebase = admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const original = 'dhara';
    const writeResult = await firestore().collection('messages').add({original: original});
    res.json({result: `Message with ID: ${writeResult.id} added.`});
});
```