# User can't write to Firestore database even though he is authorized

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I created a rule in Cloud Firestore to read/write based on wether the user is signed in through Firebase Auth or not.

From my understanding based on what I read in the official documentation, the following code should allow the signed in user the correspodent permissions to the `userID` document inside the `data` collection.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/document {
        match/data/{userId}{
                allow read, write: if isSignedIn();
         }
  }
    
    function isSignedIn(){
                    return request.auth != null;
            }
  }
```

Database image:
[image: Database]

The idea is that after the user logs in, the code I wrote should verify if there is a document called ReservedID in data/userID/ReservedID, and if there isn't, create one for him, however, this collection is never created.

It does work if I remove the security rules.

Image of the error that shows in Android Studio:

[image: Error]

However, after signing in using `mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword`, the user still can't write or read from the database. The Android Studio Logcat provides this message:

```
PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Did I misunderstood how to properly set these rules in my database? Or could it have something to do with the code itself?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Added, however, it is incomplete since the user lacks permission to write the necessary data in the database. I added a explanation on how it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are some issues with the code.

The **match** statement should specify the path to the collection and whole documents, rather than just one document. i.e you are using the path for single document `match /databases/{database}/document` instead of below path:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match/data/{userId}{

}
```

With the above changes, the code will look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match/data/{userId}{
                allow read, write: if isSignedIn();
  }
  }

  function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null;
  }

}
```

You can verify this on playground
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I made the necessary changes but the user still doesn't have the permissions to write/read from the database. I added some more information in the edit, should it help.

Comment: @LeonardoMaito can you try with this code `function isSignedIn() {
    return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
  }`

Comment: it is already set like that, I tried both ways to be sure. If I understand it correctly, the moment a user logs in using Firebase Auth, then that user is automatically verified and authorized and should be able to access the documents/collections, right?

Comment: @LeonardoMaito Yes, You are right. Once user logged in using firebase Auth, they are automatically verified and authorized to access documents/collections based on security rules set. Can you verify on `serviceAccountKey` side as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66624465/18265570)?

Comment: I believe I found the problem, it is the line:
 `request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId; `

The line `allow read: if request.auth.uid != null` works wonderfully, the issue is with the rule above.  The way I see it, it verifies if the userId that is logged in is the same one as the userId that was created when the user registered?

Comment: @LeonardoMaito I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71453707/18265570) would answer your question